# kineticJs shape with hammerjs multitouch rotation

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, kineticjs, hammer.js

Trying to binb hammerJs multi-touch into my current kineticJs 5.1 codes, found tips, but my puzzle pieces does not rotate at all, and my pieces are kinetic shape, why?

```
            var startRotate = 0;
            var hammertime = Hammer(piecesArray[i][j].shape);
            hammertime.on("transformstart", function(e) {
            startRotate = piecesArray[i][j].shape.rotation();
            }).on("transformstart", function(e) {
               piecesArray[i][j].shape.rotation(startRotate + e.gesture.rotation);
               layer.draw();
            });
```

my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This example is for KineticJS v5.1.0 and HammerJS v1.0.7*

You have to apply `Hammer` instance on `Kinetic.Node` instance, not on `Image` object.

```
var hammertime = Hammer(piecesArray[i][j].shape);
hammertime.on("transformstart", function(e) {
    this.startRatation = this.rotation();
}).on("transform", function(e) {
    this.rotation((this.startRatation || 0) + e.gesture.rotation);
    this.getLayer().draw();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/30/

**Note:** I think it is better to set another `center` for shape via `offset`.

Comment: Thanks thanks :) what do you mean by another center of offset? i can set 2 times of offset?

Comment: In my example http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/30/ shapes are rotated relative one of edges, I think it is better to rotate around center. The simplest way - config `offset` property.

Comment: currently, i added a preview picture inside my code,i can rotate my puzzle now but the problem is the sensitivity of the preview image is way too sensitive, got any way to solve that? here the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/34/

Answer (score 0):

use the latest version of hammer.js v2.0.

check out the [getting started guide](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/).
"The pinch and rotate gestures are disabled by default, enable it by"

```
hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
hammertime.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });
```

Here's an updated <strike>jsfiddle</strike>. I couldn't test it though, i can't make a rotate gesture, hope it works.

*Edit*:

The problem is, `Hammer(imageObj, options);` api expects `imageObj` to be an html element, in your case it's a kinetic shape. I don't know if you can get the html elements for each kinetic shapes. If not, you can listen to rotation on the `.kinetic-container canvas` element. So the rotation gesture is performed on the whole canvas, and you have to keep track of the last touched kinetic shape so you can rotate it.

I've setup a refactored [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/w29dgj6f/), showing the ideas i mentioned, however i couldn't manage to rotate the shape using kinetic, i hope this will fix your problem, again i couldn't test it for `rotate` but it works for `tap`.

Comment: nope, it doesnt work, any other ideas? i dont need the pinch actually. thanks :)

Comment: sorry,i tried and it doesnt work on rotate also and i dont know what else i can do,and what do you mean by it works for tap? thanks :)

Comment: @user3709279 i mean the callback fires if i listen to tap events. Do you agree with my above argument, because your code wouldn't work even for tap or any gesture not just for rotate.

Comment: ohya, it doesnt listen to any hammerjs function, but i works for kineticJs single touch function, but what i need to 2 finger rotate each of my puzzle piece, tried your method it doesnt change anything, so there`s nothing else i can do?

Comment: don't expect my example to rotate your piece, test if it actually calls the rotate callback, i can't test it, because i don't have a touch display. If it does call the callback, then the problem is not about hammerjs, it's about rotating the piece with kinetic.

Comment: @user3709279 did you read my example and see my changes, I added a variable `currentPiece` that points to the last active puzzle piece. You need to rotate that with kinetic inside your hammerjs rotate callback. If rotate doesn't work try with tap, just for testing if kinetic rotation works.